# Dropdown Menu using the 'storeLocator.Feature' in the Store Locator Library for Maps API

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, drop-down-menu

Is there any way of using a **Dropdown Menu** as opposed to the checkbox's that are used in the examples of the [Store Locator Library for Maps API](http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/index.html?utm_campaign=sl&utm_source=youtube). The checkbox is a 'storeLocator.Feature' item.

Essentially I want the user to be able to select an item from the dropdown list and this instantly change the markers on the map.

I am very new to Javascript coding but experienced in CSS, HTML and other computer languages. I have followed the examples in the link fairly closely so you can assume my own code looks the same. –

Here is the section of code i think i have to edit:

```
DataSource.prototype.parse_ = function(csv) {
var stores = [];
var rows = csv.split('\n');
var headings = this.parseRow_(rows[0]);

for (var i = 1, row; row = rows[i]; i++) {
row = this.toObject_(headings, this.parseRow_(row));
var features = new storeLocator.FeatureSet;  
features.add(this.FEATURES_.getById('Cafe-' + row.Cafe));
    features.add(this.FEATURES_.getById('Wheelchair-' + row.Wheelchair));
    features.add(this.FEATURES_.getById('Audio-' + row.Audio));

var position = new google.maps.LatLng(row.Ycoord, row.Xcoord);

var shop = this.join_([row.Shp_num_an, row.Shp_centre], ', ');
var locality = this.join_([row.Locality, row.Postcode], ', ');

var store = new storeLocator.Store(row.uuid, position, features, {
  title: row.Fcilty_nam,
  address: this.join_([shop, row.Street_add, locality], '<br>'),
  hours: row.Hrs_of_bus
});
stores.push(store);
}
return stores;
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to follow these steps:

1. **set the `featureFilter`-option of the panel to `false`**
   (this will prevent the library from creating the checkboxes)
2. **create a variable where you store all features for later use:**

   ```
   var features=view.getFeatures().asList();
   ```

   this returns an array with all features
3. **create the `select`-element**
4. **populate the `select`-element  with the needed `option`-elements**
   iterate over the `features`-array created above and append an `option` for every item to the `select` .
   The text to display inside the `option` you get by calling the `getDisplayName()`-method of the item.
5. **add a change-handler to the select with the following callback:**

   ```
   function(){
   view.set('featureFilter', 
           new storeLocator.FeatureSet(features[this.selectedIndex]));
           view.refreshView();}
   ```

   (where `view` is the `storeLocator.View` and `features` the array created in step#2)

   **5. put the select to the desired place inside the document**

Comment: Thanks Dr. Molle. You will have to bear with me as i am fairly new to Javascript. I found this text as an example select element.

<form name="myform">
<select name="master" size="1">
<option value="newsvalue">News</option>
<option value="webmastervalue">Webmaster</option>
<option value="techvalue">Tech</option>
</select>
</form>

Am i to insert an iteration over the features in the above somwhere?

Comment: wait a moment, I will setup a sample-fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/HKUrf/ The JavaScript-panel contains the relevant code with some comments, the rest of the code is taken from the [**original StoreLocator-demo**](http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/examples/panel.html) . The contents of the fiddle's JavaScript-panel are the replacement for the [**panel.js**](http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/examples/panel.js) of the original demo.

Comment: @Dr.Molle Great answer! Only one question - how do we deal with adding an option in the select list for "no features". A blank initial option which represents no features selected?

Comment: This will depend on the used DataFeed.

Answer (score 0):

Hope i'm allowed to comment here as i found this question very useful for my implementation of store locator.

Dr Molle's solution in the JS fiddle is excellent however i've just noticed that the 'directions' functionality of the map no longer works. Could this easily be rectified? thanks

edit: easier than i thought. In the fiddle "featureFilter:" is set to 'false'. A div with the class="feature-filter" needs to be present in the code for the directions to appear, setting the value to 'true' shows the div (and checkboxes) so that directions work. Checkboxes were hidden in the stylesheet..

```
.storelocator-panel .feature-filter {
/*overflow: hidden;*/ display:none
}
```

This may be useful to someone